# Последовательное выполнение функций в ajax

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Имеется код:

```
<form id="myForm" method="post">
<p><textarea id=f13 name="field1"></textarea></p>
<p><input type="submit" value="Отправить"></p>
</form>
<div id="content">1</div>
<div id="result">2</div>
 <script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
 $('#myForm').submit(function(){

var str = $(this).serialize();
var text = $('#f13').val();
var result = $('#result');

    var items = text.split('\n').map(function(item) {
        return $('<div class="result">1-' + item + '</div>');
    });
    result.html(items);

 $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "test.php",
                data: str,
                success:
                function(html){
         $("#content").html(html);
               }
            }); 
            return false;
        });

    });
 </script>

<?php 
$field1 = $_POST['field1'];
echo "Hello, <b>".$field1."</b>!<br>";
echo "Time: " . date("H:i:s") . "<br/>" . "\n";
echo "Done";
?>
```

На данный момент значения просто выходят под классом result, после того как происходит разделение массива. Есть возможность скармливать их в php по средствам ajax последовательно, но только после того, как был получен ответ Done от предыдущего из php?

Comment: доки http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ , async (default: true) - если я правильно понял ваш вопрос, то имеет смысл выставить async в false

Comment: Щас бы во времена промисов и async/await советовать синхронные запросы отправлять

Comment: В общем ваш вопрос относится к категории "ежедневный вопрос по асинхронщине в javascript". $.ajax возвращает промис довольно давно. Возможно вам поможет один из ответов на этот вопрос: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/554290/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0